# Vending machine motor: simple DC motor with microswitch, one revolution

Tags: current, motor, switches, dc

Long story short, I'm currently trying to understand and control a DC motor with connected microswitch, which gives back one-revolution feedback (don't know how). I tried connecting INA219 current sensor to circuit but current is too jumpy.

I managed to find two videos on YT, which has the exact same working principle. I'm attaching links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4QtjqgzPkk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiM3_jXN-fQ

Do we have somebody here to explain this to me? There are few post open on this theme, but zero usable answers. Maybe some vending machine expert?

I'm trying to understand and control existing DC motor. I'm attaching the pictures. From and to motor goes only two wires!

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

There seems to be a voltage peak when microswitch released. Circa 50ns.

Comment: Are you asking "How does the single revolution feedback mechanism work?" or "How do I control a DC motor with such a mechanism?" It's not clear from your "question."

Comment: A lobe of some kind (on a shaft or cam) closes the microswitch for a small part of a full rotation. You need to monitor the switch and operate the motor. You'll need a circuit to monitor the switch. You'll need a circuit to run the motor. And you'll need software that correctly monitors the switch while operating the motor. Is that all you needed to hear?

Comment: You can even hear the micro switch clicking in the video.

Comment: Ok then right questions will be:
How to properly monitor current or get feedback from microswitch?
How does the single revolution feedback mechanism work?
How do I control a DC motor with such a mechanism?

Comment: @douce I gather you have been putting in some serious work and I respect that. But I'd want to know a lot more of the story and what you already have in hand that surrounds this motor. I'd like to respect what you've done by offering serious consideration. But I can't when the view is so narrowly blinkered (using a term for horses.) Do you already have an MCU or do you want to avoid using one? I don't know. Perhaps the answer you have is all you need?

Comment: For sure I will need MCU for control. I edited my main question.

Comment: @douce Wonderful. I'm going to +1 the question and I see you are getting answers, too! [The schematic for that nice microswitch board you have (or a link to it) would be nice to have, as well. It looks as though it is set up to directly drive the motor per vir's answer. But you've said you will need an MCU. So there may be some mods ahead there, as well.]

Comment: @douce At a guess, and not knowing exactly the schematic for that board, I'd probably want to keep the entire assembly as a unit and just modify the board for use by an MCU. It appears to me (I may be wrong) that the two middle pins of the black connector don't go anywhere. This is an opportunity where you can consider providing MCU functionality via these extra two pins that are available, using all four for a new arrangement. The nice thing is that you keep the entire module, which already is mechanically sound, and just add MCU functionality to it.

Comment: @jonk I could but it goes nowhere. also I would need to replace all harness. So this is no go. 
From sampling from oscilloscope I get feedback, like voltage drop and consequently
current drop. Now I'm searching for best option to monitor current or voltage drop, which happens in 50ns.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation and couldn't understand how it worked until i found some of the comments on this question. I managed to get it to work and here is how.

The key was in sensing the current change the moment the contacts shifted from NO to NC. 
I first put a 56 ohm resistor in a series with the power pins going to the motor on the ground side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbVG6j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I monitored the voltage across the resistor which is equivalent to monitoring the current in this case. 56 ohms made the motor slower and I could see the event better on my cheapo oscilloscope

[image: The event detecting a complete rotation]

I then used a 6.8 ohm resistor (instead of the 56 ohm) in series with the motor's wires to ground. This lower value restored the motor's speed to satisfactory levels; I then used an Arduino to measure the voltage across the resistor with analogRead function. 
I got values around 150 when the motor was rotating and 0 during the brief make and break period. Using this I was able to detect the event and turn off power immediately at the end of the revolution.

In my applications i needed to control trays with 10 motors each, so I used 2 UDN2003 as a low side switches enabling me to easily use only one resistor for all the motors. 
Hoping this helps someone.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing that I have.. Signal drops for 8ms to around 10mV, then rises to 100mV,.. 
But next I have problems with ADC to Arduino, for example. Signal is very noisy.. So I'm interested how did you solve sampling with Arduino? Some Lowpass filter implemented in sw?
My contact: blazzeko007@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

I work on these units, testing and repairing them for in-service vending machines. Have restored hundreds of them.  Couple of things, the most common issue is that the microswitches become excessively noisy over time - visible noise on the scope can swamp the locating signal.  Also, most pcb have a space for a 0.1uF ceramic cap.

Installing that makes a huge difference. I use a 0.56R in my rig and it provides a nice sharp and noise-free signal after repairs.  Bit of ringing, but to be expected.  By the way, even though there are two lobes on the cam, only one is engaged on each revolution, unless the cam is inverted.  Every system I've repired uses a single pulse per rev.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:

- A cam operate the microswitch briefly when the motor leaves the "home" position.
- If the motor is powered and starts to rotate the microswitch changes state on-off-on for about 5-10 ms.
- The cam is two lobed so a second pulse occurs at the half way point
- So, I power the motor on for the time required for about 3/4 of a turn, thereby bypassing the 2nd cam lobe pulse, and then monitor for the next microswitch transition at the 1 turn point.

---

I know that this is a really old thread... but it's been invaluable for me to work out an old vending machine I'm trying to reverse engineer.

I indeed have 3x trays of vending goods (10 spirals per tray) and the problem I had was, whilst connecting 24 VDC to the motors worked, I couldn't find the way to make it only rotate one full rotation.
I could hear the click of the microswitch but was baffled .... until I read your comments!

I setup the motor on the bench and fed it 24 VDC, then connected a ULN2003A (darlington pair interface... I will need 2 for the 10 trays - and three to select each of the trays into a 3X10 matrix). The circuit:

- Connected pin 1 of the '2003A to Arduino pin D4,
- Connected pin 16 (2003A) Darlington output to the motor pin (note: polarity sensitive because motor will only spin one way due to the diode in it),
- other motor pin to +24 VDC,
- pin 8 of the 2003A to ground through a 6.8 Ω resistor (shared across all inputs, so, the right place to be monitoring voltage - as it is common to all motors).  Pin 8 connects to A0 of the Arduino.
- Ground of the motor, Arduino and power supply are all common.

The resistor is my voltage monitor divider. Ergo: when the D4 pin is set high, this switches the '2003A to active and completes the circuit to ground, turning on the motor (through the resistor that will read how much a voltage drop across it).

On the Arduino, I monitor for the voltage on A0, and wait for it to go to ZERO. This is where the microswitch opens briefly the first time.

Because this voltage is very, very noisy, in code, I switch the motor on for 2000 ms (enough time for the motor to spin 3/4 around) and ignore any voltage monitoring, then I start listening to A0 for a 0 voltage. If I see it... I stop the motor!

The 2000 ms is also sufficient for the motor to move past the second microswitch activation (that would throw a false positive).

In this example code for testing - it then waits in the loop for 5000 ms, and starts again. Eventually this 5000 ms will be dropped and will just be a void; I'll call for each motor to activate when required.

I really racked my brains over this one (and had to remember how to use an oscilloscope!).

Hope this helps someone else - thanks for the heads-up to all others involved!

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //set the Arduino to use pin 4 to switch on the 2003A
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start Serial Monitor to display current read value on Serial monitor
 }

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH); //turn on to start rotation
  delay(2000); //get past the first microswitch indent and then wait almost a full rotation before starting check
  //start for switch monitoring
  while (analogRead(A0) >0 ) //if A0 is anything other than 0 then run the motor
    {digitalWrite(4, HIGH); //keep the motor running
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0)); //show what the value is
    }
   //as soon as pulled out of the while loop - the A0 must have gone 0 so switch occurred.
    digitalWrite(4,LOW); //stop the motor
  delay(5000); //delay for testing clarity its finished - remove for production
}
```

Comment: Useful answer BUT please spell check when ready to post. It had numerous letters missed, you use small i quite often and sentences start without capitals. Some white space helps --> The end result is that the answer got flagged as low quality and it had a downvote. +1 from me .  This is a shame as it is useful. I added a summary so people could see what the overall method was. Adding to or changing that is welcome.

Comment: Made some further improvements; note that Arduino is a proper noun (capitalized), and seconds is lowercase ('S' is siemens!). You may want to draw a schematic with the editor's schematic tool, or Fritzing or something like that, to show how the devices are wired up. On that note, you had pin 8 connected to the motor, and I think you meant 16. You may want to review these changes as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A simple feedback mechanism is a normally-closed limit switch (SW1) in contact with a cam which is attached to the shaft of the motor or, more likely, the output of the gear train the motor is driving.  Adjust the positioning so that the cam presses the switch and cuts power to the motor when the vending machine dispensing coil has turned enough to drop the chips or whatever.  To start the motor, another switching element (SW2) bypasses SW1 until the cam has turned enough to release SW1.  The motor then continues to run until the cam turns around to the stop position.  SW2 can be any switching element: a PMOS/PNP or relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMGN0z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my interpretation of the circuit you have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ozEA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Based on this it seems to me that the only way to get revolution feedback from this would be to monitor current, and to look for the brief interruption as the microswitch switches over from one position to the other.

This behavior relies on the 'break-before-make' behavior of the microswitch, where there's a brief period during switchover where neither the Normally-Closed contact nor the Normally-Open contact are connected to the Common.
I would expect this interruption in current to be in the order of 100's of microseconds to maybe even as much as a couple of milliseconds.
Judging by the shape of the cam, you're going to get 2 'pulses' per revolution.

The circuit will only allow the motor to run in one direction, and the positive supply must be connected to 'P4' of the 4-pin header and 0V/ground connected to 'P1' (the wire-colors of the motor should be ignored).

Comment: This is correct. I would say this is exact same circuit. At microswitch press, we get voltage positive peak cca 40V, at release we get voltage drop to 7V in 50ns, then voltage establishes again. If I manage to monitor current or voltage in this time interval I have a solution. I tried with INA219 but this sensor is not for such precise measuring.

Comment: @douce Did you manage to find a way to detect the event with an MCU. I am facing a similar problem on a vending machine im trying to reverse engineer. The NO and NC contacts did not make any sense to me until i found your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple circuit that uses a relay to drive the motor.

[image]

Actuating the momentary push button switch energises the relay to start the motor.

The push button may be released when the 'NC' contact of the limit switch is released.

When the 'NC' contact of the limit switch is actuated after a revolution, the motor stops.

Here's another, using a controller.

[image]

Inputs are a momentary push button switch and a limit switch that is actuated once per revolution.

The output is a relay that operates the motor.

When the push button switch is actuated, the output is latched to energise the relay and start the motor.

On the limit switch being actuated, its input's rising edge resets the output to de-energise the relay and stop the motor.

The limit switch actuation may also be counted to stop the motor after the preset number of counts.