# Vending machine motor: two-pin motor assembly with microswitch

Tags: dc-motor

I am trying to replace all the electronics, except the motors, inside a vending machine with a Raspberry Pi. To achieve this I have to understand how the motors work and therefore how to drive them (I am using the two-pin variant). The motors are designed under the idea of having as few wires as possible, by having the "one revolution signal" share wires with the drive.

I can't make sense of the circuit or how to drive it, and am hoping someone can explain it to me or at least point me in the right direction.

Pic 1 is what I think the circuit is. I have attached pictures of the actual device in case I made any errors with the drawing.

Pic 1

[image]

Pic 2

[image]

Pic 3

[image]

Pic 4

[image]

Pic 5

[image]

Pic 6

[image]

Pic 7

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vending machine motor: simple DC motor with microswitch, one revolution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/619283/vending-machine-motor-simple-dc-motor-with-microswitch-one-revolution)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you have.  R1 and R2 form an extra load that increases the current drawn by the board by a few mA.  When the switch is activated, it takes a few ms to switch between terminals and the board's current drops momentarily.  The controller board should have some kind of sensor to catch this drop and tell the motor to turn off by removing input power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY1xRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks vir! I was breaking my head, and then your diagram made me realize that mine was wrong. It now makes sense. Btw the motor is in parallel with D2 and the resistors! Regards.